# Select center control/column

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid with multiple controls and I want to choose which of these controls (or which of the grid columns) will be in the center, and then have the other columns/controls just placed adjacent to it. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

The following pattern:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="MainControl's height"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="MainControl's width"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

will always force `MainControl` to be centered, as long as other controls will be defined in the `*` parts. In other words if position `[1,1]` in the above `Grid` contains your `MainControl`, you can define different `Grids` with different row/column definitions for positions `[0,0]`, `[0,1]`, ..., `[2,2]` to wrap more controls with custom size in custom locations.

For example this xaml:

```
<Window Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800" >
    <Grid x:Name="myGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="0,0"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="0,1"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="1,1"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="2,2"/>
        </Grid>
        <Button Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="1,1"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="90"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="0,0"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="1,0"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="1,1"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="2,0"/>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="2,2"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Will locate the controls this way:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work if my controls are not symmetrical (e.g. I have one small control on column 0, and one big control on column 4). Also, it forces me to specify fixed sizes for controls which I want to be of dynamic size. Consider the following XAML:
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="asdf" Grid.Column="0" />
    <Button Height="64" Width="64" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Slider Width="700" Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve in terms of layout? Your grid strategy will determine how the whole layout behaves, especially if you expect it to scale in regards to the window size. If you want the layout to react to the window size, then you use "Auto" and "Star sizing" strategies. If you actually don't care about resizing and you expect a fixed layout, then you can share grid sizes across columns.

**Scenario 1-**
If you are trying to purely achieve a middle column which contains objects of unknown size, and this column must be perfectly centered, then you need to buffer this middle column with a left and right column, as per Bahman_Aries' example.

```
<Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

The result from this is that items placed in the middle column will consume as much width as they need (the desired render width), and the two left over columns will split in two the remaining space, because each have a value of 1*. In other words, if your middle column object requests 200 width, and your window has 1000 total width, the left and right columns will both have 400 (800/2).

Note that star sized columns will crop your content when you reduce the window size. This is by design. You could consider wrapping your layouts in ViewBoxes (or the whole grid) if you want your ratios to persist.

**Scenario 2**-If you are looking for just a grid which lays out content with no regards to scaling, (re: the middle column consumes what it needs, and then the left and right columns grow equally when they have large content) then you can use the SharedSizeScope feature.

```
 <Grid IsSharedSizeScope="True">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MyRatio"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="MyRatio"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
```

What this will achieve is that whenever your column 2 grows, it will also propagate its size to column 0, essentially ensuring that your column 1 is always centered.

The main difference from Scenario 1 is that Scenario 2 will have a fixed size according to its child elements, whereas Scenario 1 has a structure which behaves in accordance to its parent container.

**Edit: Scenario 1 with an explicit example:**

```
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="4*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" x:Name="TheLeftComponents" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
    <Ellipse  Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" ></Ellipse>
    </StackPanel>
    <Ellipse x:Name="TheMiddleComponent" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Height="40" Width="40" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" ></Ellipse>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" x:Name="TheRightComponents" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <Ellipse  Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" ></Ellipse>
        <Ellipse  Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" ></Ellipse>
        <Ellipse  Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" ></Ellipse>
        <Ellipse  Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" ></Ellipse>
        <Ellipse  Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" ></Ellipse>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: This solution too assumes my layout is symmetric; what if I have my "center" column with 1 column to its left, and 100 columns to its right (and I don't know the fixed size of anything, because the whole layout changes size according to the content)?

Comment: The definition of "Centered" is by design, in the middle of something. Unless centered does not mean in the middle, you will have to clarify your question because when I read it, I understand you want to center a certain layout item.

Comment: If you are looking for a layout strategy that allows you to place an unknown amount of items to a certain side, then you are looking for a DockPanel, with Dock.Left and Dock.Right attributes on your objects. Your "middle" element would be docked Left (for example), and then all elements you add would "Dock.Right". Then it becomes a matter of placing your view appropriately.

Comment: This does not seem to do what I want, because the "middle" element is not centered. Let me explain myself. I have a certain number of controls of unknown (at design time) size, lets say 7 of them, stacked horizontally. I want a layout that will force the control #2 to always be positioned precisely in the middle of the window. The other controls will then be placed adjacent to that centered control (so, for example, #1 would be immediately to the left of #2, and #3 would be immediately to its right, #4 to the right of #3, etc).

Comment: A good example to what I'm trying to achieve is Windows Media Player's control-row, with the big Play button being the "center" element

Comment: Then scenario 1 is what you are looking for. Keep in mind that column 2 (the right sided column) can host another panel which has a large amount of items. I will try and paste you a code example as soon as I have a chance.

Comment: Ahh, I see, I didn't realize that when I first looked at Bahman_Aries's answer. The WPF mindset is somewhat hard for me to grasp. Many thanks to both of you.